# Warranty and registration removed from box, what does it mean?

Tags: extended-warranty

I received a "new" vacuum cleaner today ordered from Amazon, but the seals on the box had been neatly cut.

The only that appeared to be missing was the warranty and registration card.

So, as far as I can tell, it was either an item that had been returned unopened and then resold to me, or else someone had deliberately stolen the registration card. Why would someone do this? Is there some way to make money by stealing appliance registration cards?

Comment: Possibly some sort of mail-in-rebate?

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't new, though it may be unused. Contact the seller, and amazon, and complain. It *should* still be under manufacturer's warranty, and you do have the receipt to prove when you bought it... But if you want to register (makes getting service a bit easier, but mostly puts you on the company's mailing list) the seller owes you that and/or an unopened package.

As far as "why" goes:  It may be as simple as someone having ordered, looked at it, decided they didn't want it after all, and returning it. Or it may be an attempt to claim a rebate, though generally those require part if the box to prevent that. Or maybe they swiped your paperwork to give to the previous person to complain. Or the manufacturer *could* have missed packing it. Or...  We can't tell you which.